# Is it good practice to have my sites cert.key and cert.pem in a Nginx Docker container?

Tags: ssl, nginx, docker, lets-encrypt

Locally I have been developing with a Nginx container that has all the ssl configs and ssl certs with in a directory.

However, now that I am about to move to prod, I'm curious if having the certs in the nginx container is good practice?

Alternatively, I could place the certs on the server directly.

Curious to what the community thinks about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I would never put secrets inside a docker image. Always mounting them at container boot time. Prefer `volume` mounts over `env_var`, because `env_var` is accessible by all processes inside the container and more likely to be logged by the app.

Images should be considered shareable (across teams/envs..), but once you ship them with crucial secrets such as `cert.pem` the shareable aspect is kind of dangerous..

Also, usually not every dev on your team needs to know your prod secrets, but they are likely to have access to the docker images.

Comment: So you mount them as `volume` instead?

Comment: You can mount them as `volume` or `env_var`, but `volume` is preferred as `env_var` is easier compromised (more likely to be logged by the app and accessible by all processes inside the container..).

Answer (score 1):

you may want to take a look at Kubernetes Secrets on how to share sensitive data to your containers.  Newer versions of Docker (1.13) have a similar mechanism (docker secrets) to share secrets with containers.